# ConcurrentModifcationException happens occasionally

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I have a function with a line that is supposedly meant to prevent a concurrent modification exception 
List parseObjectKeys = new ArrayList<>(parseObject.keySet());
However it still happens every now and again

```
 private static void convertParseObject(ParseObject parseObject,
                                       HashMap<String, HashMap<String, WritableMap>> topLevel,
                                       ArrayList<Task<Void>> tasks) {
    if (parseObject != null) {
        String className = parseObject.getClassName();
        String id = parseObject.getObjectId();

        if (!topLevel.containsKey(className)) {
            topLevel.put(className, new HashMap<String, WritableMap>());
        }

        if (!topLevel.get(className).containsKey(id)) {
            final WritableMap flatMap = Arguments.createMap();
            flatMap.putString("class", className);
            flatMap.putString("id", id);

            if (parseObject.isDataAvailable()) {

            topLevel.get(className).put(id, flatMap);

            // This is required to prevent a ConcurrentModificationException
            List<String> parseObjectKeys = new ArrayList<>(parseObject.keySet());

            for (final String key : parseObjectKeys) {
                Object value = parseObject.get(key);

                if (value instanceof String) {
                    flatMap.putString(key, (String) value);
                } else if (value instanceof Boolean) {
                    flatMap.putBoolean(key, (Boolean) value);
                } else if (value instanceof Integer) {
                    flatMap.putInt(key, (Integer) value);
                } else if (value instanceof Double) {
                    flatMap.putDouble(key, (Double) value);
                } else if (value instanceof Date) {
                    flatMap.putString(key, Utils.toISO8601UTC((Date)value));
                }
                else {
                    if (value != null &&
                            !(value instanceof ParseACL)) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Unknown type: " + value.getClass());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is convertParseObject() method calls multiple time very frequently?

Comment: Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: @jiteshmohite Yes it is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HashMap` is not a thread-safe data structure, so you can use `ConcurrentHashMap` instead of `HashMap`.

use `ConcurrentHashMap<String, ConcurrentHashMap<String, WritableMap>> topLevel`
instead of
`HashMap<String, HashMap<String, WritableMap>> topLevel`.

and put `List<String> parseObjectKeys = new ArrayList<>(parseObject.keySet());`
in `synchronized` block.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution!!!**

Add synchronized block like this

```
private synchronized void convertParseObject() { }
```

Comment: This is not always true in case of using thread-unsafe data structures like HashMap.

Comment: Still, it is not a good practice to use in a concurrent environment an unsafe data structure. It can cause unwanted race conditions and unwanted loss of data consistency. Your answer is partially correct from the point of view of algorithm but not for the inner calls of HashMap's object